# LinkedList<type> filled with repeat entries

Tags: java, eclipse, linked-list

I start with a table from MySQL filled with player data for a scoreboard. It has 4 entries with different names and scores. My code sucessfully retrieves these entries. I tested this as I retrieved the entries using this method:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            String name = resultSet.getString("name");
            int score = resultSet.getInt("score");
            int lastScore = resultSet.getInt("lastScore");
            System.out.println("" + Integer.toString(id) + ", " + name + ", $" + Integer.toString(score) + ".");
            Scoreboard.addScore(id, name, score);
```

---

The `println()` returns the following four lines:

```
1, Sam, $10000.
2, Jesus, $12000.
3, Michael, $9000.
4, Asako, $4500.
```

---

`addScore()` looks like this:

```
    public static void addScore(int id, String name, int score){//Adds new score to scores LinkedList
        if (scores.isEmpty())
            scores.addFirst(new Player(id, name, score, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++){
            if (score > scores.get(i).getScore()){
                scores.add(i, new Player(id, name, score, 0));
                return;
            }
        }
        scores.addLast(new Player(id, name, score, 0));
    }
```

---

Finally, the Player class looks something like this:

```
public class Player {
    private static int id;
    private static String name;
    private static int score;
    private static int lastPosition;

    public Player(int id, String name, int score, int lastPosition){
        setID(id);
        setName(name);
        setScore(score);
        setLastPosition(lastPosition);
    }
//...
```

---

When I finally get around to displaying the scores it displays this:

1. Asako $4500
2. Asako $4500
3. Asako $4500
4. Asako $4500

Is there anything wrong with my code that could be causing this? Also, is there any code that you think could be necessary to better help you assess this question? I tried to put all of the significant code in.

---

While retrieving the scoreboard I use this code `scores.get(i).setLastPosition(i+1);`

Is that correct syntax? Can I set a value of part of the element in the LinkedList by calling get, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You class `Player` defines 4 `static` variables, which means they are defined once for the entire class, no matter how many instances of `Player` you create.  Each new instance overwrites the values, and the last one, `Asako $4500`, "wins".

Remove `static` from the 4 variables in `Player`, so that they have one value for each instance of the `Player` class.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still very new to Java. Can you also answer my follow-up question on using `get()` to set a value. Is this valid?

Comment: You should have no problem updating the desired `Player` using `get(i).whateverMethod`.  The `get()` method will return a reference to the actual `Player` object, not a copy, and you do what you like with it.